# Why does isReachable return false although the site is up?

Tags: node.js

I have this code embedded in my project but every time it runs the isReachable part the const returns false although the site is up. I am using the isReachable module. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
const isReachable = require('is-reachable');
    var url = "https://google.com/";
    function Check() {
      (async () => {
        console.log(URL);
        console.log(await isReachable('URL'));
        //=> true
    })();
    }
```

Comment: Have you enabled Cross Origin Resource Sharing in your server ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Check`-function is actually never called. So you could just simply do something like:

```
const isReachable = require('is-reachable');
const url = "http://www.google.com";
function Check() {
    (async () => {
        console.log(url);
        console.log(await isReachable(url));
    })();
};
Check();
```